# Can a Rogue (Scoundrel) with Sharpshooter Talent and Moonbow Stalker apply the crossbow bonus to her shortbow?

Tags: dnd-4e, rogue

Given:

[Rogue](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=6) with Sharpshooter Talent:

> Choose crossbows or slings. You gain a +1 bonus to attack rolls with any weapon of the chosen group. You gain Far Shot as a bonus feat, even if you don’t meet the prerequisites.

And

[Moonbow Stalker](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2895)

> Benefit: You gain proficiency with the shortbow. In addition, you can use a shortbow with Sneak Attack and with any rogue power that normally requires a crossbow.

Can she apply the benefit of sharpshooter talent to shortbows via the moonbow stalker feat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.**

And I can't see how. Moonbow Stalker explicitly lists the Sneak Attack feature and rogue powers. It does not mention that the shortbow becomes a viable choice for the Sharpshooter Talent feature.

Answer (score 1):

in raw rules no, but ask your DM, in my games i would let you do that as a house rule

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! have a look around and be sure to check out our [about] page to see how we do things around here.